# Powershell how to get-content across several subfolders

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script to output some data from multiple files based on a string search. It outputs the string found, followed by the following six characters. I can get this to work for an exact location. However, I want to search across files inside multiple subfolders in the path. Using the below script, I get PermissionDenied errors...

```
[regex] $pattern = '(?<=(a piece of text))(?<chunk>.*)'
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\*' |
ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match $pattern) {
    $smallchunk = $matches.chunk.substring(0, 6)
  }
}
    
"$smallchunk" | Out-File  'C:\Temp\results.txt'
```

If I change `-Path` to one of the subfolders, it works fine, but I need it to go inside each subfolder and execute the get-content.

e.g., look inside...

```
C:\Temp\folder1\*
C:\Temp\folder2\*
C:\Temp\folder3\*
```

And so on...

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2).  The documentation gives some examples of how to search in multiple files and subfolders.

Comment: Maybe `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\ -Filter *.txt -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $PSItem | Get-Content }` ?

Comment: @JoseFz where in that code would I put the search string "a piece of text" ?

Comment: Just continue using your pipeline after `Get-Content`. BTW, the code (as-is) takes the `C:\Temp\results.txt` file as well… I'd start using `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\ -Filter *.txt -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $PSItem.FullName}` to see particulars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on [boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog)'s suggestion of `Select-String`, the only limitation would be folder recursion. Unfortunately, `Select-String` only allows the searching of multiple files in one directory.

So, the way around this is piping the output of `Get-ChildItem` with a `-Recurse` switch into `Select-String`:

```
$pattern = "(?<=(a piece of text))(?<chunk>.*)"
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\" -Exclude "results.txt" -File -Recurse | 
    Select-String -Pattern $pattern |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        $_.Matches[0].Groups['chunk'].Value.Substring(0,6)
    } | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\results.txt"
```

If there's a need for the result to be saved to `$smallchunk` you can still do so inside the loop if need be.

Comment: `chunk` is the self-chosen name of a regex capture group (`(?<chunk>.*)`)

Comment: @mklement0, I figured having the pipe inside the loop wouldn't be as consuming rather than having it outside waiting for the loop to finish; got any reason you think I should change that? That explains it, I'm just not familiar with RegEx enough to have understood that :')

Comment: To me, the `-Append` approach has two drawbacks: (a) you must ensure that the target file is empty beforehand and (b) opening and closing the file every time you write a match is time-consuming. Note that even with `Out-File` in a separate, final segment _streaming_ processing occurs; that is, each match is written as it is emitted by `ForEach-Object`; the only difference is that the file is only opened and closed once.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can I observe that; *in regards to the opening and closing of the file*? So following the `Foreach-Object` with `Out-File` there wouldn't be a need to use `-Append`? I guess that makes sense, let me update it to reflect that. Thank you btw.

Comment: @mklement0 in an ideal world `Out-File` would detect more input is coming from the pipeline and would keep the file stream opened :p

Comment: @Abraham Correct: no need for `-Append` with `Out-File` in its own, final pipeline segment: whatever pipeline input is received, irrespective of what and how many other cmdlets are involved is written, is saved to the output file. `Out-File` of necessity has to close and open the output file every time it is called - if it didn't, it would leave the file open. However, with pipeline input it opens (creates) the output file in the `begin` block, loosely speaking, writes all pipeline input in the `process` block, and then closes the file in the `end` block.

Comment: @Santiago, but that's exactly what it does with its pipeline input; you just need to make sure that everything to be written to the file is provided by a _single_ pipeline.

Comment: big oof, I should've known that.

Comment: @mklement0 yeah I know, I meant to say when using the `-Append` switch but that wouldn't be possible

Answer (score 2):

**[Abraham Zinala's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72550766/45375) is the best solution to your problem**, because letting `Select-String` search your files' content is faster and more memory-efficient than reading and processing each line with `Get-Content`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> Using the below script I get PermissionDenied errors...

These stem from *directories* being among the file-system items output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), which `Get-Content` cannot read.

If your files have distinct filename extensions that your directories don't, one option is to pass them to the (rarely used with `Get-Content`) `-Include` parameter; e.g.:

```bash
Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\* -Include *.txt, *.c
```

However, as with [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string), this limits you to a *single* directory's content, and it doesn't allow you to limit processing to *files* fundamentally, if extension-based filtering isn't possible.

For *recursive* listing, you can use `Get-ChildItem` with `-Recurse`, as in Abraham's answer, and pipe the file-info objects to `Get-Content`:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\Temp -Include *.txt, *.c | Get-Content
```

If you want to simply limit output to *files*, whatever their name is, use the `-File` switch (similarly, `-Directory` limits output to *directories*):

```bash
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse C:\Temp | Get-Content
```